# How does a 'covenant' differ from a [1] 'promise' [2] 'contract'?

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms, england-and-wales

I'm discombublated why none of my contract law textbooks define 'covenant' when they use it many times, including [*Anson's Law of Contract* (2016 30 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ansons-Law-Contract-Jack-Beatson/dp/0198734786/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=ZW82SGPZDB8D0GKSVMV4) and [*Contract Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (2018 8 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Contract-Law-Text-Cases-Materials/dp/019880816X/ref=dp_ob_title_bk).

Google furnished some articles defining 'covenant', but in US law  by

- [Eric Lambert](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/representations-warranties-covenants-why-theyre-matters-eric-lambert/) [BA in Economics, Math, Business, University of Rochester. JD Cornell.](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ericesquire/)
- [Raymond Millien](https://www.ipwatchdog.com/2018/10/10/contracts-101-covenants-representations-warranties-ip-license-agreements/id=102186/)  BS in Computer Science from Columbia University (New York), and a JD from The George Washington University Law School (Washington D.C.)
- [Marc Primack](https://www.natlawreview.com/article/representations-warranties-and-covenants-back-to-basics-contracts) [The University of Chicago, AB, Phi Beta Kappa. Stanford University, JD](https://www.dresslerpeters.com/professionals/marc-a-primack).
- [Upcounsel.com](https://www.upcounsel.com/difference-between-covenant-and-contract), but I distrust this as the author(s) is undeclared.

[Thomson Reuters Practical Law's glossary](https://practicallaw.thomsonreuters.com/8-107-6009?transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)&firstPage=true&bhcp=1) is too snippety.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

A proper definition was given by the Ninth [Circuit](https://www.adamsdrafting.com/how-a-court-determines-whether-something-is-an-obligation-or-a-condition/):

> A covenant is a contractual promise, i.e., a manifestation of
>   intention to act or refrain from acting in a particular way, such that
>   the promisee is justified in understanding that the promisor has made
>   a commitment. A condition precedent is an act or event that must occur
>   before a duty to perform a promise arises. Conditions precedent are
>   disfavored because they tend to work forfeitures. Wherever possible,
>   equity construes ambiguous contract provisions as covenants rather
>   than conditions. However, if the contract is unambiguous, the court
>   construes it according to its terms.

See the entire [opinion](http://www.koncision.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/MDY-Industries.pdf)

According to Cornell web [dictionary](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/covenant):

A covenant is a promise in a contract or contract-like legal agreement.  For example, lease agreements include covenants to pay rent.

So, a covenant is a type of promise and it is part of the contract or agreement. A contract will have other clauses and a covenant is one of them.

Comment: I'm asking about English law though. Can you cite an English case?

Comment: The book Contract Law, by Neil Andrews, offers several examples and cases.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any difference in the legal effect of a "covenant" than a promise or contract, and I've never seen a case that has made that distinction with any legal effect.

For example, a land covenant could also be called "a land use agreement" or a "property restriction" or a "negative easement", instead of a covenant, with the same legal effect.

The term covenant is customarily used for promises that run with the land, or for promises made in connection with a financing transaction (e.g. a "loan covenant"). The term covenant is also sometimes used as a synonym of "provision" or "section" within a contract or agreement or lease or legal instrument that contains a promise.

But, it isn't improper or incorrect to use the term in most other contexts, even though it would be non-standard in some of them. "Covenant" is often used redundantly in a phrase such as "contracts, covenants and agrees" in all sorts of contracts, which simply reflects the common practice of using redundant terminology in legal transactions.